# Is there a way to specify using regex to show results not containing specific text

Tags: java, regex

Is there a way to  specify using regex to show results not containing specific text.Something similar to

> Select * from table where id not in {3,4,6};

Comment: give a sample String and what you expect as a result

Comment: As in a negative lookahead? http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: There is, but you should be more specific on what you need. Usually `^` is used for small regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[^346] -any character except 3,4,6. Is this what you asked?

Answer (score 0):

How about simply looking for the text, and use the not operator on the result?

```
List<String> list = ...
list = list.stream()
    .filter(string -> !string.matches("[346]")) // note the !
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

In keeping with your example, consider this code:

```
Stream.of("13","11","3","33","3a")
  .filter(s -> s.matches("(?!3$|4$|6$)\\d+"))
  .forEach(System.out::println);
```

It will select only those strings which are pure digits, but do not match "3", "4" or "6".

The key feature of the regular expression is

```
(?!3$|4$|6$)
```

This is the negative lookahead, and it matches the exact strings "3", "4", and "6". Since it's *negative*, the whole expression matches when this part does not match.